# Why the Thread crashes at the second call?

Tags: android, multithreading, onclick

I have a really simple program. On `activity_main.xml` I have only the following `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="play"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:scaleX="2"
    android:scaleY="2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play" />
```

Tapping the image, it should start the following activity.

```
public void play(View view) {
        Log.i("Luigi","ciao");
        WORD.start();
    }

public Thread WORD = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        }
    };
```

As you can see, the activity is totally empty so it shouldn't give any problem. And it works if I tap the image the first time. The problem is that at the second time that I tap the image, the program crashes.

Has anyone got a reason of this? I can't really explain this behavior, also because I left the activity totally empty.

**SOLVED**

I solved with AsyncTask in the following way.

```
public void play(View view) {
        Log.i("Luigi","ciao");
        new WORD().execute();
    }

    private class WORD extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            return "Work executed!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you have to interrupt the Threat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Thread API, specifically the `start()` function:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

Calling `start()` on a thread that is already running will throw an exception, which is what is happening in your case.

What is the point of having the thread anyways? If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to help you.

Also, take a look at the logcat in Android Studio, it will help you finding the cause of crashes.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response. I need to run an animation that the user can't stop touching other objects. During the animation, the user can do other activities. To do this, I have read on the internet that `Thread` is the way. Or there is a better way?

Comment: You could try AsyncTask

Comment: @ARP sorry but I can't understand. How can I apply AsyncTask in this case? Can you kindly show me an example?